# Problem with the Rigging of legs, and it's doing stranger things!

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging

First of all, sorry for my bad english.
So I use blender for a few time, I rigged a lot of basic 3D model ( especially voxel character ), but this time i tried to create a real and professional rig.
So, here's my problem : when i create automatic rig, it rigs both legs, so if I move the feet... both legs move strangely.
I tried mutiple thing, like removing the mirror modifier of the mesh with the vertex group off, rigging with few basic bones, etc etc... but nothing works. It's my first time with this bug, so If anyone has a solucion, please can you help me xD. Thanks in advance.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your model is one object, it's actually in two separate halves with all the vertices down the middle overlapping. I guess this has confused Rigify somewhat!
If you go into Edit mode, hover the cursor over one side of the model and press 'L', you'll see it just selects one half and you can move it around without the other side moving. There are actually 116 overlapping vertices right down the centre of the model. Go into Edit mode, select the whole model with 'A' and then join them with 'M' and then Merge By Distance.
I'd delete the armature and rig, join the model as mentioned above and try again with a fresh armature.

Comment: after removing these vertice, i created a new rig, but the same problem appear again, I never saw this kind of problem before. I think I will use a simpler rig and change the weight by myself.

Answer (score 0):

The weight is bad, for example if I select this left leg bone, you can see that it affects the right leg, so you need to correct that:

[image]

Comment: I know, but the things is : why does the automatic weight bugs on this model ? I use it thousand times on other and similar model and i never had this bug

Comment: it can happen and in that case you need to correct with a brush of with the vertex group assign button

Comment: Ok, thanks ! I will try !